# How to write an incremental backup script using rsync

Tags: backup, rsync, incremental

I am trying to implement custom function for backup using `rsync`. For this, I modified the following exist code https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-incremental-backups-using-rsync-on-linux as follows:

```
#!/bin/zsh
#https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-incremental-backups-using-rsync-on-linux

# A script to perform incremental backups using rsync

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

incremental_bckp_rsync_dir(){
  readonly SOURCE_DIR="/$1"
  readonly BACKUP_DIR="/$2/$1"
  readonly DATETIME="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')"
  readonly BACKUP_PATH="${BACKUP_DIR}/${DATETIME}"
  readonly LATEST_LINK="${BACKUP_DIR}/latest"
  
  mkdir -p "${BACKUP_DIR}"
  
  rsync -av --delete \
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/" \
    --link-dest "${LATEST_LINK}" \
    --exclude=".cache" \
    "${BACKUP_PATH}"
  
  rm -rf "${LATEST_LINK}"
  ln -s "${BACKUP_PATH}" "${LATEST_LINK}"
}


incremental_bckp_rsync_dir path/to/dir path/to/backup
```

It does successfully a backup of the `dir`, however the size of the backup dir (obtained with the command `du -h path/to/backup`) seems to double every time I run the script (which means that it is not incremental, from what I understand. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @jhnc. the size of the backup dir is measured with `du -h path/to/backup`

Comment: does your filesystem support hard links?

Comment: @jhnc. I think but I am not sure. How can I know if it does?

Comment: eg. `find "$LATEST_LINK/" -type f -links +1 -ls | head`

Comment: Is this MacOS? Does its `du` default to using `-l` maybe?

Comment: `cd "$BACKUP_PATH"; mkdir test; cd test; dd if=/dev/zero bs=10M count=1 > f1; du -h .; ln f1 f2; du -h .; cp f2 f3; du -h .; ls -l`

Comment: so @jhnc for `find "$LATEST_LINK/" -type f -links +1 -ls | head` I get `9288501280        8 -rw-r--r--    7 User01            staff                   7 Apr 11 18:34 path/to/dir/latest//backedupfile.txt`

Comment: `"$BACKUP_PATH"; mkdir test; cd test; dd if=/dev/zero bs=10M count=1 > f1; du -h .; ln f1 f2; du -h .; cp f2 f3; du -h .; ls -l` gives me `dd: bs: illegal numeric value`

Comment: Well, you definitely have hard-links (`... 8 rw-r--r-- ...`). The `dd` command is just trying to create a large file, then hard-linking it (and checking if `du` changes - it shouldn't), and then copying (and checking if `du` changes - it should). `dd if=/dev/zero bs=200b count=100` might work, or just copy in a biggish file from somewhere.

Comment: I'm suspicious that it is `du` that is reporting unexpected values, rather than that `rsync` is not correctly hard-linking. You could try `df`  instead, and see if it also reports unexpected increase.

Answer (score 0):

Exists a tool that use rsync and organize backup folder into catalog for easy future use...
The tool is Butterfly Backup. I find this article (and also its documentation) that explain how works: https://fedoramagazine.org/butterfly-backup/

Docs: https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/Butterfly-Backup

Simple use:

```
bb backup --computer pc1 --destination /nas/mybackup --data User Config --type MacOS --mode Full
```

And catalog is:

```
bb list --catalog /nas/mybackup
...
BUTTERFLY BACKUP CATALOG

Backup id: f65e5afe-9734-11e8-b0bb-005056a664e0
Hostname or ip: pc1
Timestamp: 2018-08-03 17:50:36

Backup id: 4f2b5f6e-9939-11e8-9ab6-005056a664e0
Hostname or ip: pc1
Timestamp: 2018-08-06 07:26:46

Backup id: cc6e2744-9944-11e8-b82a-005056a664e0
Hostname or ip: pc1
Timestamp: 2018-08-06 08:49:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this but you could use the `-n` | `--dry-run` option to have `rsync` just list all files it would transfer (so all changed, deleted and new files), e.g.:

```
rsync -an --delete --out-format="%f" src_path/ dst_path
```

and store it's output to a file and then start another `rsync` with the `--files-from` option to feed it with this list to only transfer these files to a different destination (with timestamp in it's path etc).

Another approach (I mostly use) is to have `rsync` create backup (mirror) and store a copy of modified/deleted files in a seperate path with the `-b` | `--backup` option. E.g.

```
TIMESTAMP=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S')
rsync -av --delete --backup --backup-dir=$DEST/DELETED/$TIMESTAMP" $SRC/ $DEST
```

Which will keep your backup in sync but also create an extra backup of old files in a seperate folder under ./DELETED/ at each run on your destination. Usually you want to keep only backups from the last X days so you have to create a delete-job what purges older folders under $DEST/DELETED/.